# How to define column that doesn't have NAs in sequence of certain rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, sequence

Here is some sample data:

```
    df1 <- read.table(text = "Date  Client1 Client2 Client3
                  01.01.2019    0   0   2
                  01.02.2019    0   0   3
                  01.03.2019    0   0   4
                  01.04.2019    0   0   4
                  01.05.2019    0   0   4
                  01.06.2019    1   0   4
                  01.07.2019    0   0   0
                  01.08.2019    0   0   1
                  01.09.2019    0   0   0
                  01.10.2019    0   3   0
                  01.11.2019    0   0   2
                  01.12.2019    2   0   0
                  01.01.2020    3   4   3
                  01.02.2020    4   0   3
                  01.03.2020    5   0   0
                  01.04.2020    5   0   0
                  ", header = TRUE)
df1[df1 == 0] <- NA
```

And the question is how to find a logical index for every column that contains a sequence of 5 or more rows that doesn't contains NAs.

```
Client1 TRUE
Client2 FALSE
Client3 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `rle()` function to count run lengths of `!is.na()`.  For example, using your definition of `df1`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Name = character(3), Group = character(3))

for (i in 1:3) {
  runs <- rle(!is.na(df1[, i + 1]))
  good <- which(runs$values == TRUE)
  runs <- runs$lengths
  n <- length(runs)
  df2$Group[i] <- if (n %in% good) "Stable"
                  else if (max(runs[good]) >= 5) "Was_Stable"
                  else "Not_Stable"
  df2$Name[i] <- names(df1)[i + 1]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for question beign changed. Thought it would be hard to answer it. Therefore made it simplier. But for that question that was in the past i got (`Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "Stable") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated `)

Comment: Sounds like you're using an old version of R, which converts characters to factors.  You should upgrade to 4.0.3.

Comment: Problem solved by `df2 <- data.frame(Name = character(ncol(df1)), Group = character(ncol(df1)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. But i got an error if there more than 3 colmns (Clients): `Error in [.data.frame(df1, , i + 1) : undefined columns selected`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` to iterate over columns and check with `any` :

```
sapply(df1[-1], function(x) any(with(rle(!is.na(x)), values & lengths >= 5)))

# Client1 Client2 Client3 
#   TRUE   FALSE    TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644346/5861244), then you can use `rle` like this:

```r
# add a column with no NAs as an example
df1 <- cbind(df1, dummy = 1:NROW(df1)) 

# find columns with five or more NAs in a row
is_num <- vapply(df1, is.numeric, TRUE) # assume we only look at numerics?
res <- setNames(rep(TRUE, NCOL(df1)), colnames(df1))
res[is_num] <- vapply(df1[is_num], function(x){
  o <- rle(!is.na(x))
  any(o$lengths[o$values] > 4)
}, TRUE)
res
#R> Date Client1 Client2 Client3   dummy 
#R> TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
```

I would expect this to be quite fast. If you do not
care about the other columns, then you can do:

```r
is_num <- vapply(df1, is.numeric, TRUE)
vapply(df1[is_num], function(x){
  o <- rle(!is.na(x))
  any(o$lengths[o$values] > 4)
}, TRUE)
#R> Client1 Client2 Client3 
#R>    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE
```

I realise after the fact that this is only a minor twist to the [answer by Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64645922/5861244). Combining his approach with my solution yields this:

```r
vapply(df1[vapply(df1, is.numeric, TRUE)], function(x)
  with(rle(!is.na(x)), any(lengths[values] > 4)), TRUE)
#R> Client1 Client2 Client3 
#R>    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE
```